# Как убрать расстояние между блоками div?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap, отступы

Как сделать, чтоб блоки не равнялись по самому большому, а прижимались к верхнему?
Мой код:

```css
.col-sm-4 {
   border: solid 1px #6c757d;
   padding: 10px;
   width: 33.33333333%;
   float: left;
   padding-right: 15px;
   padding-left: 15px;
   margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="col-sm-4">A1</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">A2 text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">A3 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">A4</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">A5</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">A6</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">A7</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">A8</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">A9</div>
</div>
```

Пример на **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dsq8a3wb/)**

Comment: Да, иное. https://jsfiddle.net/dsq8a3wb/2/  A4 прижался к A1 а A5 к A2 и так далее по аналогии, чтоб они не равнялись по самому большому.

Comment: С этим понятно. Разница в высоте блоков всё равно какая? Или же тут тоже есть какие-то ограничения? (имею ввиду отражаемый контент в блоках)

Comment: Да, все блоки разной высоты. И сделать их одинаковыми по высоте нет возможности, разный контент.